# selecting suitable options from list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, select

I have a list of sentences. For example:

```
x = ['Mary had a little lamb', 
           'Jack went up the hill', 
           'Jill followed suit',    
           'i woke up suddenly',
           'I just missed the train',
           'it was a really bad dream']
```

I want to select those options in which the penultimate word is not 'the'.
How could i do it on python 3?
I tried this:

```
l = []
for i in x:
    for k in i: 
        if i.index(k) != (len(i) -2):
             l.append(' '.join(i))
```

I works on a small lists but not on huge ones(several thousands elements)

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: How does your code "work"? It does not even have `"the"` anywhere in it. Just seems like a very inefficient way to add `len(i)-1` "spaced" copy of each string to the result list.

Comment: its part of code, i also have a list of words which shouldn't be penultimate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `filter()` method and pass through a lambda which will return true for strings which don't have `"the"` as the second last word:

```
x = ['Mary had a little lamb', 
           'Jack went up the hill', 
           'Jill followed suit',    
           'i woke up suddenly',
           'I just missed the train',
           'it was a really bad dream']

res = list(filter(lambda str : str.split()[-2] != "the", x)) 
print(res) # ['Mary had a little lamb', 'Jill followed suit', 'i woke up suddenly', 'it was a really bad dream']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension with `split` to separate the sentence into words, then use index `[-2]` to check the penultimate element.

```
>>> [s for s in x if s.split()[-2] != "the"]
['Mary had a little lamb',
 'Jill followed suit',
 'i woke up suddenly',
 'it was a really bad dream']
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
x = ['Mary had a little lamb', 
           'Jack went up the hill', 
           'Jill followed suit',    
           'i woke up suddenly',
           'I just missed the train',
           'it was a really bad dream']

result = [y for y in x if y.split()[-2].lower() != 'the']

print(result)
# ['Jack went up the hill', 'I just missed the train']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = ['Mary had a little lamb', 
           'Jack went up the hill', 
           'Jill followed suit',    
           'i woke up suddenly',
           'I just missed the train',
           'it was a really bad dream']

res =[sentence for sentence in x if 'the'!= sentence.split()[-2]]

print(res)
```

output

```
['Mary had a little lamb', 'Jill followed suit', 'i woke up suddenly', 'it was a really bad dream']
```

Comment: if 'the' is not penultimate?